# How to create xml in esql

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am trying to create an xml of the below format

```
<Item Value = '1234'>
     <Value>5678</Value>
</Item>
```

I got a clue from

```
DECLARE sp1 NAMESPACE 'http://www.ibm.com/space1';

/* Namespace declaration to associate prefix 'space1' with the namespace */

SET OutputRoot.XMLNS.TestCase.(XML.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:space1 = 'http://www.ibm.com/space1'; 
SET OutputRoot.XMLNS.TestCase.sp1:data1 = 'Hello!';
```

generates:

```
<TestCase xmlns:space1="http://www.ibm.com/space1">
<space1:data1>Hello!</space1:data1>
</TestCase>
```

Any inputs will be really helpful

Comment: Sounds as if you need to learn the basics of the product first. I recommend watching some introductory videos. After that, import some of the product samples ( there are loads of them ) and look at how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those looking for question similar to this..
This is what worked for me

```
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC Type XMLNSC.Folder Name 'Item'; 

SET OuputRoot.XMLNSC.Item.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name = '1234';
```

This generates the `<Item Value = '1234'>` part

Comment: Actually, the first line is not required. It will create a field with name 'Item' under OutputRoot.XMLNSC. But SET statement on the second line will auto-create that field for you.